# How to SELECT just one Item in SQLite? (localStorage)

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, cordova

I'm trying to make my code better by being more specific with the SQL queries:

The following code works and I can work with the results. But probably not the most efficient:

```
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM foo', [], querySuccess);
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    console.log(results.rows.item(0).name);
}

OUTPUT: JOHN
```

---

So when I try:

```
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT id FROM foo WHERE id = 1', [], querySuccess);
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    console.log(results.rows.item(0).name);
}

OUTPUT: undefined
```

I've tried using different numbers on the query and on the array but nothing works. I assume that the query is wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: You are selecting id but your output is name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for a start do you *have* a row where the ID is 1?

Secondly, since you're only selecting the `id` column in your second statement, why do you think you're going to be able to access `name`?

Thirdly, it makes little sense to limit your query to the first row without an `order by` clause. SQL is free to return the rows in any order it wants without that clause.

If you really want the name for the first ID in the table, something like:

```
select name from foo order by id limit 1
```

should do the trick. There are very few use cases where it makes sense to do `select *`.

If you want the fourth row, use something like:

```
select name from foo order by id limit 1 offset 3
```

See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) for more details.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot.

I'm still figuring out the logic behind SQL. Learning just by reading examples is a bit hard for me!

Thanks for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `LIMIT 1` to your query. Here is example:

```
SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What if I want to select the 4th row? should I use LIMIT 4? Or is there a more direct way?

Comment: @ricardolobo use `LIMIT 3, 1` (first is offset, second is limit)